# using midpoint rule approximate $\int_0^4 \cos{\sqrt{2x}} \space dx$ dx with $n=10$

Tags: calculus

Every time I calculate this I get close to the right answer but my decimals are always off by a little I don't understand why I can't get the right decimal numbers.

Comment: write how you did it

Comment: Welcome to this site! Your post does not contain a question as such, and so cannot be answered.  Could you give us more detail and write a precise question?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're doing the approximation with

[image]

implying your ith test point would be

[image]

It could be that you're just overlooking a test point by accident.